# WSUS edge update fail 0x80070643

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-edge, wsus

it's a little bit of time that one of my clients do not install from wsus server the update for microsoft edge properly.
After the install get to 100% return the error code 0x80070643.
Already tried to install manually (download edge business from ms site), reset all windows update components.
Other updates are installed succesfully.
The event log report a different error code (only a generic installation errore with code 0x8024200B).
The very wierd part is that if I disable the wsus policy and check for update in edge information page, the update install succesfully.
Other clients install it from wsus without issues.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm, it's looking for the original installer path. If Edge was installed via group policy place the installer that Edge rolled out with back under software installation in the Edge rollout policy. I had removed my 105 installer with a newer version 107 and I was having all sorts of issues getting the Edge updates to apply. I figured the 107 installer would suffice in place of the 105, but apparently not. I placed the original installer that Edge rolled out with back under software installation in group policy and the Edge updates started working properly once again. Hope this helps someone in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but as I did not find a solution this nowhere I decided to give answer here in case it helps somebody else.

**TL;DR The issue was that the newer installer needed access to the previous installer to uninstall(?) the older version before installing the newer one on top of that. **

I was fighting against this same error for almost two weeks before I found the solution at least in my case. I have a local WSUS-server where workstations try to download certain Ms Edge update and always end up with the 0x80070643 error.

I downloaded the same version of the Edge installer to a USB-stick and tried to install it manually to one of the workstations giving the error. The installer told me that a certain network resource was unavailable even though I was installing the file locally! I browsed the required file share path directly from the file server and found out that there was an older version of the same Edge installer-exe which the newer installer was craving. This lead to finding out that the user account installing the Edge from the USB-stick did not have the network share mapped. Giving the direct \server\share name to the installer it finally was happy and installed the Edge without errors.

I still have to solve the network share issue but at least edge was installed properly and windows update no longer gives me any errors.